# Bar not rearranging with flex in css

Tags: css

I have a working code for flex in css. Although the buttons are realigning but the blue bars is not moving. Due to this changing the screen size make it seem that all the buttons have disappeared.

```
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body
{
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position : center;
    
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menu-bar
{
    background: #273044;
    text-align: center;
    height:30px;
     
}
.menu-bar ul
{
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style: none;
    color: #fff;
    
}

.menu-bar ul li
{
width: 120px;
place-items:center;
display: grid;
 
padding: 5px;  
}

.menu-bar ul li a
{
text-decoration: none;
color: white;   
}
.active, .menu-bar ul li:hover
{
background-color: #0b56ab;
height:auto;

height:30px;
} 

.toggle-button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.75rem;
    right: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 31px;
    height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar{
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;

}

@media(max-width: 700px){
    .toggle-button{
        display:flex;
    }
    .menu-bar-links{
        /* display:none; */
        width:100%;
    }
    .menu-bar{
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flexstart;
    }
    .menu-bar-links ul{
        width:100%;
        flex-direction: column;

    }
    .menu-bar-links li{
        text-align: center;
    }
}


/* body{margin:0; padding:0; font-size:13px; font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; color:#919191; background-color:#232323;} */
```

This is my HTML Code:

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <title> Title of page    </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet1" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.1/css/fontawesome.min.css">
    </head>

<!----header----> 
    <body> 
        <div class="menu-bar">
            <a href = "#" class="toggle-button">
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>

            </a>
            <div class="menu-bar-links">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Investors</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Training </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
     </div>



        <!-- <div class= "grid"> 
            
        </div> -->

    </body>
</html>
```

This is how it looks when in full screen:
[image]

When i rearrange the screen it looks like this:
As you can see all the buttons seems to have disappeared except the one which is hovered over

[image]

It is also not centering even with

```
.menu-bar-links li{
        text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you have a fixed height on your `.menu-bar`, namely `height: 30px`. You're better off removing that, adding some padding for presentation and making the `.menu-bar` element a `flex` container.

**Link to CodePen:**

https://codepen.io/thechewy/pen/QWQQMjg

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu-bar {
  background: #273044;
  text-align: center;
  /*   height: 30px; */
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.menu-bar ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-bar ul li {
  width: 120px;
  place-items: center;
  display: grid;
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu-bar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.active,
.menu-bar ul li:hover {
  background-color: #0b56ab;
  height: auto;
  height: 30px;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 31px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }
  .menu-bar-links {
    /* display:none; */
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu-bar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flexstart;
  }
  .menu-bar-links ul {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .menu-bar-links li {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title> Title of page </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet1" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.1/css/fontawesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu-bar">
    <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="menu-bar-links">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Investors</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Training </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```